Multi-output Tensorflow model does not output loss for each output
I am using an example from Geron's Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit Learn, Keras, and Tensorflow book (3rd edition). This example can be obtained https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3.
The example code I am referring to is in Ch. 10, under the section: Using the Subclassing API to Build Dynamic Models:
class WideAndDeepModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=30, activation="relu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # needed to support naming the model
        self.norm_layer_wide = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.norm_layer_deep = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.main_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.aux_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        input_wide, input_deep = inputs
        norm_wide = self.norm_layer_wide(input_wide)
        norm_deep = self.norm_layer_deep(input_deep)
        hidden1 = self.hidden1(norm_deep)
        hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
        concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([norm_wide, hidden2])
        output = self.main_output(concat)
        aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
        return output, aux_output

tf.random.set_seed(42)  # extra code – just for reproducibility
model = WideAndDeepModel(30, activation="relu", name="my_cool_model")

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(loss="mse", loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["RootMeanSquaredError"])
model.norm_layer_wide.adapt(X_train_wide)
model.norm_layer_deep.adapt(X_train_deep)
history = model.fit(
    (X_train_wide, X_train_deep), (y_train, y_train), epochs=10,
    validation_data=((X_valid_wide, X_valid_deep), (y_valid, y_valid)))
eval_results = model.evaluate((X_test_wide, X_test_deep), (y_test, y_test))
weighted_sum_of_losses, main_loss, aux_loss, main_rmse, aux_rmse = eval_results
y_pred_main, y_pred_aux = model.predict((X_new_wide, X_new_deep))

which should in theory give:
Epoch 1/10
363/363 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 1.3490 - output_1_loss: 1.2742 - output_2_loss: 2.0215 - output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 1.1288 - output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 1.4218 - val_loss: 1.5415 - val_output_1_loss: 0.9593 - val_output_2_loss: 6.7806 - val_output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.9795 - val_output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 2.6040
Epoch 2/10
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5101 - output_1_loss: 0.4785 - output_2_loss: 0.7952 - output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.6917 - output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 0.8917 - val_loss: 1.3624 - val_output_1_loss: 1.0094 - val_output_2_loss: 4.5401 - val_output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 1.0047 - val_output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 2.1307
Epoch 3/10
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.4618 - output_1_loss: 0.4404 - output_2_loss: 0.6546 - output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.6636 - output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 0.8091 - val_loss: 0.5361 - val_output_1_loss: 0.3975 - val_output_2_loss: 1.7837 - val_output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.6305 - val_output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 1.3356
Epoch 4/10
363/363 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.4252 - output_1_loss: 0.4059 - output_2_loss: 0.5985 - output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.6371 - output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 0.7736 - val_loss: 0.5182 - val_output_1_loss: 0.4590 - val_output_2_loss: 1.0517 - val_output_1_root_mean_squared_error: 0.6775 - val_output_2_root_mean_squared_error: 1.0255

This output is taken from the Jupyter notebook provided - I didn't actually get this output.
I can't run this code right off the bat because Tensorflow complains with:
ValueError: For a model with multiple outputs, when providing the `metrics` argument as a list, it should have as many entries as the model has outputs. Received:
metrics=['RootMeanSquaredError']
of length 1 whereas the model has 2 outputs.

which I can fix with just adding another 'RootMeanSquaredError'. My main issue is getting the following output during training:
Epoch 1/10
66/66 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 3ms/step - RootMeanSquaredError: 0.4504 - RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4841 - loss: 0.2072 - val_RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3687 - val_RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4427 - val_loss: 0.1420
Epoch 2/10
66/66 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1ms/step - RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3633 - RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4302 - loss: 0.1374 - val_RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3614 - val_RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4205 - val_loss: 0.1352
Epoch 3/10
66/66 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 2ms/step - RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3568 - RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4135 - loss: 0.1317 - val_RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3564 - val_RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4134 - val_loss: 0.1314
Epoch 4/10
66/66 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1ms/step - RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3519 - RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4075 - loss: 0.1281 - val_RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3510 - val_RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4096 - val_loss: 0.1277
Epoch 5/10
66/66 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 1ms/step - RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3475 - RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4041 - loss: 0.1250 - val_RootMeanSquaredError: 0.3469 - val_RootMeanSquaredError_1: 0.4063 - val_loss: 0.1248

Why am I only getting loss and val_loss despite having 2 outputs? The other outputs correspond to the metrics for each output. I am expecting loss, output_1_loss, output_2_loss, etc.
I have tried removing the metrics keyword argument and only loss and val_loss are printed during training. I also tried different custom subclassed Model classes with the same result. I also tried creating a model with the Functional API and got the same thing.
Tried setting verbose=2 with no change. Tried single input (as opposed to two inputs) with no change.
Tried setting the name argument for the output layers and passing dictionary arguments:
model.compile(loss={'out0':'mse','out1':'mse'}, loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics={'out0':'RootMeanSquaredError','out1':'RootMeanSquaredError'})
history = model.fit(
    (train_feat[0], train_feat[1]), {'out0': train_label[0], 'out1': train_label[1]}, epochs=10,
    validation_data=((val_feat[0], val_feat[1]), {'out0': val_label[0], 'out1': val_label[1]}))

with no change.
Tried passing the a list of loss=[tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), tf.keras.loss.MeanSquaredError()] with no change.
One post seems to have the same issue, with the fix of using the metrics to monitor instead:
how to get loss of each output in multi output regression?
Another post seems to get exactly what I want with same settings:
Only show total loss during training of a multi-output model in Keras
I'm using Python 3.9, Tensorflow 2.17.0, and Keras 3.4.1. Is there something I'm missing?

Upgrade to Keras 3.5.0 solves the error
